# Get available languages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, localization, cultureinfo

i am trying to get the available languages installed in visitors pc's.
The problem is that i don't want to get the languages from the internet browser.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: In ASP.NET, the text on a page is coming from the server, so why do you need to know what languages the user has installed locally on their PC? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to display my webpage in two languages. Greek and English. If user has available the "el-GR", the Greek version of my website should be displayed. Believe it or not, although my native language is Greek, i have installed the English-based Firefox version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only (standard) way is to look in the HTTP header's 'Accept-Language'. See [the standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). It would be a security hole if you could get access to more information than that without asking permission.

You could run some Active X component to spy on the users' computers, but you'd have to get them to give you permission first, but I suspect that will just cause people to not want to use your website. Also it would only work on Windows. I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Of course, you can always ask your users to tell you via some settings page. If changing this setting would help them to use your site, they would probably not mind doing that.

Comment: just what Mark said in the 1st paragraph. Full stop.